# Compute external loss function but compute gradients in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function

I want to train a model for which the loss function can only be computed externally. So, I take the output of my last layer, compute some value externally and want to use this to update my network. Can I implement such a setup in tensorflow?

Comment: You can only do this if this external computation also uses TensorFlow so the gradient can propagate correctly through it, if its a black box, then no, you can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you have to define your minimised loss out of the graph, for example:

```
loss = Network.loss(input_tensor)
loss_2 = out_function(loss)
```

And then you just have to specify :

```
train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss_2)
```

It should work